# Using CILanczosScaleTransform Core Image Filter to resize an image

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

I am trying to use the `CILanczosScaleTransform` Core Image Filter to resize an image, but I am running into problems. Here is my code:

```
var imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
var image: UIImage?
imageView.frame = CGFrameMake(10,10,200,300)
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    let nsurl = NSURL(string:"http://...")
    var err: NSError?
    var getImageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: nsurl!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &err)
    if let imageData = getImageData {
        if let receivedImage = UIImage(data: imageData){
            image = receivedImage
/*
  so far all this code works fine, if I set imageView.image = image 
  the image displays with no problems...

  ...the problems are in this bit of code:
                                                    */
            let context = CIContext(options:nil)
            var ciimg = CIImage(image: image)
            var filter = CIFilter(name: "CILanczosScaleTransform")
            filter.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            filter.setValue(0.667, forKey: kCIInputScaleKey)
            let result: CIImage = filter.outputImage

            let extent = result.extent() // <-- specifically this line

            let newImage: UIImage? = UIImage(CIImage: result)
            imageView.image = newImage
        }
    }
})
```

When execution reaches the line `let extent = result.extent()` I get the following runtime error:

```
-[UIImage extent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a457790
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage extent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a457790'
```

I translated the code I found on [Apple's Core Image Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH3-SW1) from Objective C over to Swift, and feel like I might of mistranslated it.

Can anyone put me right?

Comment: Code works fine for me except the `CGFrameMake`, but that's irrelevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok this was my mistake. This line: `filter.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)` is using the `UIImage` found in `image` and using it inside the filter, when instead it should be using the `CIImage` found in `ciimg`.

So the complete code should be:

```
var imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
var image: UIImage?
imageView.frame = CGFrameMake(10,10,200,300)
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    let nsurl = NSURL(string:"http://...")
    var err: NSError?
    var getImageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: nsurl!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &err)
    if let imageData = getImageData {
        if let receivedImage = UIImage(data: imageData){
            image = receivedImage
            let context = CIContext(options:nil)
            var ciimg = CIImage(image: image)
            var filter = CIFilter(name: "CILanczosScaleTransform")
            filter.setValue(ciimg, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            filter.setValue(0.667, forKey: kCIInputScaleKey)
            let result: CIImage = filter.outputImage
            let extent = result.extent()
            let newImage: UIImage? = UIImage(CIImage: result)
            imageView.image = newImage
        }
    }
})
```